# How to Connect Empty Cells in C# interop library

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I want to generate an excel graph in C#, I want Connect Empty cells in chart. How is this in C# interop library?

in Excel I choose "*Connect data point with line*" in "*Hidden and Empty cell as*".

Thanks

Comment: Try to record a macro and see how it's done using the macro. Then try it in C# using excel interop.

Comment: thanks for your comment, It's possible to say more details

Comment: [Automate tasks with the Macro Recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b). Then you can see the code generated for the macro and see how you can automate it the same way that macro is doing.

Comment: Its Worked . Thank you very much.

Comment: I set chart.DisplayBlanksAs to xlInterpolated;

Comment: You can share your answer here, including some description and your code. Maybe future readers find it useful.